# C++ Memory Barriers for Atomics

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, memory-barriers

I'm a newbie when it comes to this. Could anyone provide a simplified explanation of the differences between the following memory barriers?

- The windows `MemoryBarrier();`
- The fence `_mm_mfence();`
- The inline assembly `asm volatile ("" : : : "memory");`
- The intrinsic `_ReadWriteBarrier();`

If there isn't a simple explanation some links to good articles or books would probably help me get it straight. Until now I was fine with just using objects written by others wrapping these calls but I'd like to have a better understanding than my current thinking which is basically along the lines of there is more than one way to implement memory barriers under the covers.

Comment: you forgot about C++11s `atomic_thread_fence`

Comment: Well that's what this is leading to ... we have our own atomic template object for integral types and I'm wanting to switch to C++11 standard atomics. Before doing so I want to understand the underlying implementation of how both actually work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Both `MemoryBarrier` (MSVC) and `_mm_mfence` (supported by several compilers) provide a hardware memory fence, which prevents the processor from moving reads and writes across the fence.

The main difference is that MemoryBarrier has platform specific implementations for x86, x64 and IA64, where as _mm_mfence specifically uses the `mfence` SSE2 instruction, so it's not always available.

On x86 and x64 MemoryBarrier is implemented with a `xchg` and `lock or` respectively, and I have seen some claims that this is faster than mfence. However my own benchmarks show the opposite, so apparently it's very much dependent on processor model.

Another difference is that mfence can also be used for ordering non-temporal stores/loads (`movntq` etc).

GCC also has `__sync_synchronize` which generates a hardware fence.

`asm volatile ("" : : : "memory")` in GCC and `_ReadWriteBarrier` in MSVC only provide a compiler level memory fence, preventing the compiler from reordering memory accesses. That means the processor is still free to do reordering.

Compiler fences are generally used in combination with operations that have some kind of implicit hardware fence. E.g. on x86/x64 all stores have a release fence and loads have an acquire fence, so you just need a compiler fence when implementing load-acquire and store-release.

Answer (score 5):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280119/how-do-memory-fences-work/7280317#7280317) on the hardware level semantics of fences. What is not mentioned there is that they also prevent reordering of loads, stores or loads & stores(depending on the fence) *across* fences, at both compiler level and hardware level.