# atomic memory ordering and interrupting a message loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the following two threads of execution:

Thread A:

```
// Initialize stuff...
std::atomic<bool> interrupted = false;

// Launch thread B
// ... Do some useful stuff

// Interrupt B
interrupted = true;
InterruptMessageLoop(B);
```

Thread B

```
RunMessageLoop(); // Can exit by itself or due to InterruptMessageLoop
if (interrupted) {
    // Do something special
}
```

The question that I have is - can I be sure that in case the thread A indeed call the InterruptMessageLoop, thread B will see the `interrupted` atomic in a `true` state? (I refer to this as "desired behaviour" below)

The problem that I see here is that, if I understand it correctly, the memory ordering of `std::memory_order_seq_cst` that is used in `operator=` of the atomic variable guarantees that no normal **writes** will be reordered **after** the atomic operation and no normal **reads** will be reordered **before** the atomic operation. But it may happen that thread A reorders the `InterruptMessageLoop(B)` before the atomic, then thread B interrupts the message loop and reads the incorrect (regarding the logic I want) value of `interrupted` and only then thread A writes to `interrupted`. Is that correct? And if yes, is there a way to make sure that I get the behaviour I want without resorting to a mutex (i.e. wrap the InterruptMessageLoop and boolean modification into a mutex and lock the same mutex on read)?

Note, that I have no control of the implementation of `RunMessageLoop`.

**Edit**
Note that the situation when I issue the command to interrupt the loop and the loop exists normally (kind of ignoring my command) - it's fine in my case that thread B thinks that the interruption caused the message loop to exit.

Answer (score 0):

To accurately differentiate whether RunMessageLoop finished normally or due to InterruptMessageLoop, you'll have to rely on some sort of status that RunMessageLoop tells you.

The hacky way you are trying to do won't work. Say you managed to guarantee that the compiler does not record anything. You still have the following interleaving:

- T1: (A) interrupted=true
- T2: (B) RunMessageLoop() finished normally.
- T3: (A) InterruptMessageLoop()
- T4: (B) if (interrupted) returns true, but B was NOT interrupted!

Comment: Thanks. However, as I said in the note - I have no control over the implementation of `RunMessageLoop`, so I can't really differentiate the two situations based on whatever it says to me. However, the situation you described is perfectly fine - I'm worried only for the case of when I issue the command to interrupt the loop and afterwards I can't say that I did from within thread B.

Comment: I couldn't tell from your original description that you tolerate certain errors but not certain other errors, when deciding whether RunMessageLoop was indeed interrupted by thread A. But in that case, have a look at memory barrier e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841738/c-memory-barriers-for-atomics. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand this was totally unclear - thanks for pointing this out! I'll look into the memory barriers.