# "asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");" does not work in c++

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly, memory-barriers

I was trying to follow the queue implementation in [this blog](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/lock-free-multi-producer-multi-consumer-queue-ring-buffer) that uses a memory barries like below:

```
asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
```

But the same is not working for me and throwing this error:

> error C2589: ':': illegal token on right side of '::'

How to express the same memory barrier in c++11?

Comment: That looks like an MSVC error message, can you confirm? And that's GCC inline assembly, so it won't work with MSVC.

Comment: Yes MSVC - what is the MSVC equivalent to achieve the same?

Comment: This notation for inline assembly is for the gcc compiler and other compilers that maintain compatibility with it - notably clang and the intel compilers. Microsoft compilers have their own syntax for inline assembly.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh - see this question: [C++ Memory Barriers for Atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841738/c-memory-barriers-for-atomics). A more recent list of intrinsics (better than using asm when available) is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list). These documents in turn suggest using [`atomic_thread_fence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/atomic-functions?view=msvc-160#atomic_thread_fence) from `<atomic>` facilities.

Comment: That whole blog is written using gcc intrinsics which won't work at all in MSVC.  In this day and age I would think you'd want to use `<atomic>` instead.  The author complains that gcc doesn't optimize the `<atomic>` functions well enough, but that's based on a very old version, and you're not using gcc anyway.  Maybe you want to see if you can find a more up-to-date implementation.