# Tell Optimizer (O2) two Pointers are the 'same' (LLVM Linux Armv7)

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, clang++

I have a class that has 2 pointers to a external memory p_Data and p_DataWrite. Most of the time, both of those pointers point to the same memory and are used to read said memory (p_Data) or write said memory (p_DataWrite). I now have a case in which I write the memory (using p_DataWrite), then read the memory (using p_Data). When I compile this with clang++ for the ARMv7 platform for Linux using O2 I get the effect, that the memory gets read first und written afterwards. I tried using the p_Data pointer to write the memory and the effect is gone. That is not a option for the project.

I see the effect only for ARMv7 Linux with at least O2. I also build my project for x86_64 Linux and for x64 Windows and can compile with O2 and above without this issue.

How can I tell the compiler/optimizer that those two pointers are the 'same' and it is not allowed to change the execution order?

Edit Add Example Code:

```
        *((unsigned int *)IN_Class.p_DataUserWrite) = 0x12345678;

        unsigned short In_Word = *((unsigned short *)IN_Class.p_DataUser + 0);
        unsigned short Out_Word = (unsigned short)((In_Word >> 8) | (In_Word << 8));

        In_Word = *((unsigned short *)IN_Class.p_DataUser + 1);

        *((unsigned short *)OUT_CLass.p_DataUserWrite + 1) = Out_Word;
        Out_Word = (In_Word >> 8) | (In_Word << 8);
       
        *((unsigned short *)OUT_CLass.p_DataUserWrite) = Out_Word;
```

translates to

```
;         *((unsigned int *)IN_Class.p_DataUserWrite) = 0x12345678;
   1f2b8: e5923034      ldr r3, [r2, #0x34]
   1f2bc: e5920030      ldr r0, [r2, #0x30]
;         *((unsigned short *)OUT_CLass.p_DataUserWrite + 1) = Out_Word;
   1f2c0: e5911030      ldr r1, [r1, #0x30]
;         unsigned short In_Word = *((unsigned short *)IN_Class.p_DataUser + 0);
   1f2c4: e1d320b0      ldrh    r2, [r3]
;         In_Word = *((unsigned short *)IN_Class.p_DataUser + 1);
   1f2c8: e1d330b2      ldrh    r3, [r3, #2]
;         *((unsigned short *)OUT_CLass.p_DataUserWrite + 1) = Out_Word;
   1f2cc: e6bf2fb2      rev16   r2, r2
   1f2d0: e1c120b2      strh    r2, [r1, #2]
   1f2d4: e3052678      movw    r2, #0x5678
   1f2d8: e3412234      movt    r2, #0x1234
;         *((unsigned int *)IN_Class.p_DataUserWrite) = 0x12345678;
   1f2dc: e5802000      str r2, [r0]
;         *((unsigned short *)OUT_CLass.p_DataUserWrite) = Out_Word;
   1f2e0: e6bf0fb3      rev16   r0, r3
   1f2e4: e1c100b0      strh    r0, [r1]
;     }
   1f2e8: e12fff1e      bx  lr
```

Comment: Generally, I would say there is no way to force a compiler to optimize the code in a specific way. Optimization is a best effort process and is never perfect.

Comment: Not quite what you are asking, but it seems a [memory barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841738/c-memory-barriers-for-atomics) would help you.

Comment: Declare `p_Data` ad `p_DataWrite` pointers as `volatile`. This will prevent the C++ (and C) compiler from reordering reads and writes.

Comment: Alternatively, duplicate your code: `if (p_Data == p_DataWrite) { /* Use p_Data for both reads and writes */ } else { /* Use both p_Data and p_DataWrite */ }`.

Comment: Can you show us (a simplified version of) your code and the `-O2` assembly output with the reordering? Maybe there is standards-compliant change to prevent reordering optimizations, but first we need to understand why the optimization is done at all.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the reordering (https://godbolt.org/z/d3axaKr3n), so it's not always happening. Please show us your simplified source code and the `clang -O2` assembly output with the reordering

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @DanielLangr: Re “it needs to assume that both parts may overlap”: When memory is accessed with different types other than as permitted by the aliasing rule (C++ 2020 7.2.1 [basic.lval] 11), the compiler may assume the accesses with different types point are different memory locations. E.g., if a routine is passed `int *p, short *q`, and `*p` and `*q` are used to access memory, the compiler may assume they do not overlap. If a routine is passed `int *p, int *q`, the compiler may not assume they do not overlap.

Comment: @EricPostpischil According to the description of the problem, I originally assumed that both pointers were of the same type. But it turned out now that this was not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

In `*((unsigned int *)IN_Class.p_DataUserWrite) = 0x12345678;` you write to the address using the type `unsigned int`. This differs from the type used to access the address in other lines, where `unsigned short` is used.

Accessing the same memory with two different types other than as listed in C++ 2020 7.2.1 [basic.lval] 11 violates the aliasing rule in that paragraph. Then the behavior is not defined by the C++ standard. The import of this is that the compiler does not have to treat an access as `unsigned int` and an access as `unsigned short` as if they might access the same memory. So the optimizer is free to rearrange this code as if the addresses were different.

Clang has a feature to tell the compiler to support aliasing memory with different types, and the `-fno-strict-aliasing` switch requests that.

Alternatively, you could modify the code to use only `unsigned short` to access the memory, separating the write of `0x12345678` into two writes of an `unsigned short`.

Comment: Another option is to use `char*` (and `memcpy` I suppose) which already allow for aliasing (thwarting relevant optimizations).  Note, for the comment above, `volatile` won't prevent aliasing related optimizations.

Comment: Thank you very much, -fno-strict-aliasing did the trick, and again I'm amazed at the knowlegde that waits on stackoverflow for people doing not defined things!